# Tensor product of fields 2

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, fields, hopf-algebras, tensor-products

Let $K_1, K_2$ be finite field extensions of a field $k$.

> Question: Is it true that $A=K_1 \otimes_k K_2$ is isomorphic to a product of group algebras over fields?
>
> Question 2: In case the answer is negative, we still have that $A$ is a symmetric Hopf algebra. What is the group of group-like elements?

Comment: Previous question with same title: [Tensor products of fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280044/)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Take $K_2=k$, do you really believe that every finite field extension is a product of group algebras?

Comment: @abx In that case $A=K_1 G$ for $G$ the trivial group, or? I think it always works in case $A$ is semi-simple.

Comment: Oh, I see, you allow a group algebra over a field extension. Sorry I missed that.